# Error when validating formula

Tags: microsoft-access-2010

I am trying to create a field to convert currencies from one of 2 fields, thus I am putting the following code in "Default Value" as I want this field to be open for my manual input too:

```
=iif([£ Price]>[$ Price],EuroConvert([£ Price],[GBP],[EUR]),iif([$ Price]>[£ Price],EuroConvert([$],[USD],[EUR]),"0"))
```

MS Access is giving me this error anytime I try to save the table:

> The Database engine could not recognize either the field "£ Price" in the validation expression, or the default value in the table "Table Name".

Worst of all, MS Access isn't providing anything in its knowledge-base about it. Also:

- I don't have anything in "validation rule"
- And this is the only "Default Value" Expression I used.